# Chart Web Part Average Data of a coumn

Tags: web-part

Let say I have a list with

```
Title | Result A | Result B
bob       1           1
bill      1           3
ben       1           5
```

I wish to graph the average for Result A and Result B only.

Using the Chart Web Part I can show the mean/median on the graph but it appears as line but I cant add the results up and just show that.

Any ideas how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Some possible options

1) Add an event receiver to your list to summarise it to another list on add/edit/delete and graph the summary list.

2) Use Excel Services to summarise the list and provide a chart

3) Look at other 3rd party chart web parts such as [PivotPoint](http://blog.pentalogic.net/2011/04/sharepoint-charting-in-pivotpoint-%E2%80%93-coming-soon/).

*(Disclaimer - made by my company)*